# How to make image show up next to para tag p

Tags: html, css

How can we make image show on right side of the paragraph where `<p>` i tried but it is always coming under  `<p>`

example on fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/ECEka/44/`

```
<div class="service-list">
    <p>text goes here text goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes here
    text goes here text goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes here</p>
        <p>text goes here text goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes here
    text goes here text goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes here</p>
    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png" alt="icon" width="200" height="auto" />
</div>
```

Comment: Should the image be inside <p>?

Comment: No image will be outside `<p>`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the order of html: put `<img>` before `<p>`;

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ECEka/49/)

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I wonder why didn't it work when i did the same.. may be my `display` time was set as `inline-block` anyways thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to put the image inside the `p` tag (at the top) and then float it right.

[**JS Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ECEka/50/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="service-list">
    <p>text goes here text goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes here
        text goes here text goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes here</p>
    <p>
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png" alt="icon" width="200" height="auto" />text goes here text goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes here
        text goes here text goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes heretext goes here</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.service-list {
    width: 600px;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    display: block;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.service-list p img {
    float:right;
}
.service-list p {
    text-align: left;
    display:block;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Check your link to jsfiddle, seems it's the same as op's.